# nvd3 charts: Is it possible to change margin dynamically?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

Is it possible to change margin of the chart after drawing it? Just like I can hide legend etc.

I can do something like this:

```
chart.margin({
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
});
```

But I want to use different left margin for different width of the chart (resizeable div by jQuery).

Comment: Can you redraw after changing the margin?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can redraw automatically on resize by doing something like `nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart svg').call(chart) });` (adjust for your element ID).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm drawing the chart and then I do $div.data('chart', chart) to save the variable. And then when I do d3.select('svg').call($div.data('chart')) I get "Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: Try `chart.update()` to redraw an existing chart (in terms of window resizing, that would become `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)`). Never tried that after changing a margin, though.